# How to add string to current value in mongoose updateMany()

Tags: mongoose

// node js mongoose
//ids = ['id1','id2'] for example

```
const usersUpdated = await User.updateMany(
  { _id: { $in: ids } },
  [
    { $set: { username: { $concat: ['$username', deletedFormate] } } }
  ],
  { multi: true, new: true },
  function(error, result) {

  }
);
```

//I need to add string after all match username
//for example if updateMany() find 2 doc
//1. username = "m2012" I want to add "55555" with m2012 and after update it will be //"m201255555"

Comment: Answer posted. Please approve and upvote my answer if you like my efforts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please follow below method for using $concat

```
let query = {
    _id: {
        $in: ids
    }
};
let changes = {
    $set: {
        username: {
            "$concat": ["$username", deletedFormate]
        }
    }
};
let usersUpdated = await User.updateMany(query, [changes]).lean();
console.log(usersUpdated);
```

**Note:**  The above method work only for mongodb version 4.2 and above